# How to melt/stack a 2-factorial multivariate DataFrame from wide to long format?

Tags: python, r, pandas

Say, we are given a two-factorial (M)ANOVA design, i.e., the sampling design consists of two categorical variables with two and three levels respectively and a response of dimension 4. Let us also assume that the data are given in wide format were the first two variables describe the design and the last four variables the response. (So, the crux is that the design variables are already in long format, but the response variables are not.)

How do I melt the data into long format?

The solution in R:

```
 # Data managment
 library(reshape2)

 # Creating sample data
 set.seed(12345)
 dat = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(42*4, mean=c(10,3,5,1)), ncol=4, byrow=T))
 names(dat) = c('Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End')
 gen = factor(sample(2, size=42, replace=T), labels=c('WT', 'HET'))
 env = factor(sample(3, size=42, replace=T), labels=c('heavySmoker', 'casualSmoker', 'nonSmoker'))
 dat$genotype = gen
 dat$environment = env

 # Melting
 melt(dat, measure.vars=c('Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End'))
```

The problem in python:

```
 # Numerics
 import numpy as np
 from numpy.random import randint

 # Data managment
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame
 from pandas import Series

 # Creating sample data
 np.random.seed(12345)
 index = pd.Index(np.arange(42))
 frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(42,4) + np.array([10,3,5,1]), columns=['Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End'], index=index)
 genotype = Series(['WT', 'HET'], name='genotype', dtype='category')
 environment = Series(['heavySmoker', 'casualSmoker', 'nonSmoker'], name='environment', dtype='category')
 gen = genotype[np.random.randint(2, size=42)]
 env = environment[np.random.randint(3, size=42)]
 gen.index = frame.index
 env.index = frame.index
 frame['genotype'] = gen
 frame['environment'] = env

 # How to melt?
 frame.stack() # How to stack only the four response variables?
```

I know, or at least assume, that I have to use the functions frame.stack() and frame.unstack() in some fashion, but was, unfortunately, very unsuccessful in doing so.

Comment: stack as in add rows to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) function:

```
In [139]: pd.melt(frame, id_vars=['genotype', 'environment'], value_vars=['Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End'])
Out[139]:
    genotype   environment variable      value
0        HET     nonSmoker     Base   9.795292
1         WT   heavySmoker     Base  11.965781
2        HET   heavySmoker     Base  10.769023
3        HET  casualSmoker     Base  10.274992
4        HET   heavySmoker     Base   7.998363
5         WT  casualSmoker     Base   9.460259
6         WT   heavySmoker     Base   9.422913
7        HET     nonSmoker     Base  10.000940
...
```

For using (the bit more low-level) `stack` method, you first need to set the index (and will have to rename the columns afterwards):

```
In [136]: frame.set_index(['genotype', 'environment']).stack().reset_index()
Out[136]:
    genotype   environment  level_2          0
0        HET     nonSmoker     Base   9.795292
1        HET     nonSmoker  State23   3.478943
2        HET     nonSmoker  State42   4.480561
3        HET     nonSmoker      End   0.444270
4         WT   heavySmoker     Base  11.965781
...
```